# Cannot install dotnet-svcutil offline

Tags: .net, .net-core, svcutil.exe

I'm trying to install dotnet-svcutil tool on a server that has no internet connection. Visual Studio is also not installed on the server.

.NET 7 SDK is already installed on the server,

```
dotnet --version
```

gives:

> 7.0.100

I have downloaded the tool from https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-svcutil

Then I tried to do offline installation using the following command:

```
dotnet tool install  -g dotnet-svcutil --add-source D:\Install\dotnet-svcutil.2.1.0.nupkg
```

but unfortunately I get the following error:

> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\3\a3fdc36c-b100-4e78-99ba-3f987d505581\restore.csproj
> : error NU1301: The local source
> 'D:\Install\dotnet-svcutil.2.1.0.nupkg' doesn't exist. The tool
> package could not be restored. Tool 'dotnet-svcutil' failed to
> install. This failure may have been caused by:
>
> - You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
> - A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
> - The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
> - You mistyped the name of the tool.
>
> For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit
> https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool

Is there anything else I could try in order to install the tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just folder location without filename as a source:

```
dotnet tool install  -g dotnet-svcutil --add-source D:\Install --ignore-failed-sources
```

**NOTE:**

As you are installing being offline you need `--ignore-failed-sources` flag. Nuget feed is unavailable and your installation will fail if one of the sources is unavailable. Feeds are accessed in parallel. [From here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-install):

> --add-source <SOURCE>
>  
> Adds an additional NuGet package source to use during installation. Feeds are accessed in parallel, not sequentially in some order of precedence. If the same package and version is in multiple feeds, the fastest feed wins

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had already tried using the folder name instead of full path, so I think  `--ignore-failed-sources` did the trick.